# Polymer updating array subproperty by model

Tags: arrays, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm having some issues with arrays in [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/). I have an array of categories, containing an array of items. These items contain several properties that I'd like to easily mutate. For this example, I would like to toggle the `item.enabled` property. This is the template layout:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{categories}}" as="category">
    <span>{{category.name}}</span>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{category.items}}" as="item">
        <span>{{item.name}}</span>
        <span>{{item.enabled}}</span>
        <paper-icon-button icon="error" on-tap="toggleEnabled"></paper-icon-button>
    </template>
</template>
```

I want the `toggleEnabled`-call to toggle the `enabled`-property of that specific item that is part of that category.

AFAIK, to update the `item.enabled` property so that the templates get updated, I need to call Polymer's [`set()`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#set-path) method. This method needs to be invoked with the path to that item property (as a String) and the value:

```
this.set('categories.x.items.y.enabled', !item.enabled)
```

In this call, x is the category-index and y the item-index. The issue with this is that I'm not sure how to (efficiently) get these two parameters from the `toggleEnabled` call. I know how to get the item itself:

```
toggleEnabled: function(e) {
   var item = e.model.item;
}
```

but other than by excessive filtering I'm not sure how I can retrieve the indexes to update the property of the item to get the template updated.

What am I overlooking and what is the most effective way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE: 2016-01-03**

For the above-mentioned use-case, the easiest way is to directly set the event `model` object.

tap-handler:

```
toggleEnabled: function (e) {
  e.model.set('item.enabled', !e.model.item.enabled);
}
```

If it's necessary to know which **parent** your subproperty belongs to, bind the `category-index` as an attribute of your icon button; else, the alternative requires dom-traversal which adds unnecessary complexity.

template:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{categories}}" as="category" index-as="cat_index">
    <span>{{category.name}}</span>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{category.items}}">
        <span>{{item.name}}</span>
        <span>{{item.enabled}}</span>
        <paper-icon-button cat-index$="{{cat_index}}" icon="error" on-tap="toggleEnabled"></paper-icon-button>
    </template>
</template>
```

tap-handler:

```
toggleEnabled: function (e) {

  var target = Polymer.dom(e).localTarget; // Normalize the event
  var cat = target.getAttribute('cat-index'); // The parent index
  var item = e.model.index; // Subproperty index

  // Do your stuff
  var enabled = this.categories[cat].items[item].enabled;
  this.set(['categories', cat, 'items', item, 'enabled'], !enabled);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Totally forgot about the index, seems to work very well thanks! Only issue I had was with `e.target.getAttribute()`. The target returned an `<iron-icon>`, but the `dataHost` propery of the target does return the correct element, so this line is changed to `e.target.dataHost.getAttribute('cat-index'')`. Thanks!

Comment: Upon further inspection, sometimes `e.target.dataHost.getAttribute('cat-index')` results in an illegal invocation

Comment: I ended up not using the `cat_index` by just using the `set()` of the model: `e.model.set('item.enabled', !e.model.item.enabled)`.

Comment: @jdepypere sorry, just saw your messages. I forgot - shadow dom automatically retargets the event so if you capture the event on the `paper-icon-button` node, the `target` object will naturally be that. If you're running on shady dom, you'll need to normalize it. I'll edit my answer to make this clearer.

Comment: Also, I honestly didn't realise the `set` method is mixed into the `model` object! (pretty sure that wasn't in the past) Glad you posted this.